# Mac Command Line Tools Continue to Update

Tags: macos, command-line, high-sierra, mac-appstore, homebrew

This morning, I decided to re-install MacOS High Sierra using macOS Recovery by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>. The system got stuck when only 11 minutes were remaining.

I restarted it and did the same process again, only this time, it wanted to install OS X Mavericks. I continued installing it. Once OS X Mavericks was installed, I updated it to macOS High Sierra. It said it was installed but it was only downloaded.

I found it was downloaded in `/Applications` folder and did the install. Everything worked like it should.

I started to install Homebrew, but Command Lines Tools were not installed, and started installing it. Then I saw Command Line Tools update in the App Store, so I cancelled the one initiated by Homebrew and initiated installation from the App Store.

Now, in App Store, it keeps on showing update Command Line Tools for OS X El Capitan and macOS High Sierra.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you removed all Xcode from /Applications and then rerun the `brew` or `xcode-select —Install` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line/34617930#34617930?newreg=157d2573329147a684fc6b2c506eebef This answer solved the issue, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore the update shown in the App Store. Install Command Line Tools by running the command:

`xcode-select --install`

In case the command doesn't work, and gives an error stating,

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

simply run `brew config`. It will show a dialogue box asking to accept Xcode license terms. Once accepted, Command Line Tools will be setup successfully.

Comment: Since I installed the command lines tools via App Store update, this command does not work. It says `command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`.

Comment: Try running `brew config` and look for the value corresponding to `CLT:`.

Comment: When I ran `brew config`, it asked to accept Xcode terms. Then the value next to `CLT` is `9.3.0.0.1.1521514116`

Comment: Bingo! CLT is now successfully setup on your machine . `9.3.0.0.1.1521514116` is the current version as of this writing. I have edited the answer to cover the discussed additional steps.

Comment: I have to run just update from another window "macos / preferences / software update" --- make no sense separate that "advanced instalations" from window "app store" --- "softwareupdate --install -a" https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617930/1347601

Comment: When I run `brew config` after installing XCode CLI tools (after manually deleting XCode.app folder), I get: `Clang: xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app`` But I have no idea where it installed to.

Comment: @PetrusTheron I had the same problem after migrating from a Mac with an older OS to a newer Mac. The only thing that helped was running: sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/